# Base64 Image Not Showing Up, Breaking In Safari

Tags: safari, base64, mobile-safari

I am setting the images as base64 strings, and they show perfectly in Google Chrome, but in Safari it shows blue question marks.

Tried different approaches, such as adding this piece of code

```
var iosImg = new Image;
iosImg.src = encodedImgString;
iosImg.crossOrigin = 'Anonymous';
```

And adding extra '=' at the end of the base64 string

But it still breaks.

This is how the tag looks like:

```
<img class="dark" id="image-tab1-107" src="data:image/jpeg; base64,/9j/4RA/RXhpZgAATU0AKgAAAAgA.......QcWHKu/X+mFBf/Z">
```

Comment: Can you show an actual example?

Comment: Just added the tag I'm using

Comment: No, you posted PART of the tag.

Comment: Have you looked here?  https://stackoverflow.com/q/1207190/535275

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So apparently there was a space between ; and base which I inserted there while combining the string, while Chrome could fix it by itself Safari broke the image.

Comment: THIS seems to be the key!!